# Exact value $\sin(160^\circ)\sin(140^\circ)\sin(110^\circ)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am looking for the exact value of $a = \sin(160^\circ)\sin(140^\circ)\sin(110^\circ)$.

The hard way would be to compute each factor, wich is doable, and basically amounts to compute trigonometric values for $20^\circ=\frac{\pi}{9}$. But this computation involves the resolution of a cubic equation, which I would like to avoid (that's for a preCalculus class that didn't know about methods cubic equations).

I am looking for a more elegant way using trigonometric formulas like the Product-to-Sum formula and similar ones. Does anyone have an idea on this?

The anecdote is that I know such a method exists (a friend showed it to me a while back) but I cannot remember it.

Comment: Did you mean to ask for $\sin(160^\circ)\sin(140^\circ)\sin(100^\circ)$? This does have a nice closed form.

Comment: If that is what you intended to ask, a quick Google search yields [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120316121149AAAbh7i).

Comment: From @ComplexPhi's answer, it seems that my memory is wrong and you are right. That's embarassing... Is there a way I can save the question without invalidating ComplexPhi's answer? (thanks for the edit)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi9.html could be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3):

First use $\sin(180^{\circ}-x)=\sin x$ so :

$$a=\sin 20^{\circ} \sin 40^{\circ} \sin 70^{\circ} $$

$$a=\sin 20^{\circ} \sin 40^{\circ} \cos 20^{\circ}$$

Now use $\sin x \cos x=\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}$ :

$$a=\frac{\sin^2 40^{\circ}}{2}$$ and this hasn't a nice form .

Answer (score 1):

I will use that:
$\sin(a)=\sin(180-a)$, $\sin(a)=\cos(90-a)$ and $\sin(2a)=2\sin(a)\cos(a)$.

$\sin(160)\sin(140)\sin(110)=\sin(20)\sin(40)\sin(70)=\sin(20)\sin(40)\cos(20)=\frac{\sin^2(40)}{2}.$